# How can I show results in a select input, based on values shown in a seperate table?

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables, and I'm just looking for a way to make this work.

`tbl_campaigns` has the columns "id" and "campaign". This one is fairly straight forward, it's just campaign names with an ID number that is auto-incremented so they have unique IDs.

`tbl_users` has an "id" column so each user has a unique ID number, standard stuff.

`tbl_permissions` creates a new row whenever a new user is created. This means its "id" column has unique ID values that match to the ID of a user in 'tbl_users'. The columns have been named to match the ID value of a campaign each time a new one is created, for example, the column "campaign_1" is relevant to the campaign in 'tbl_campaigns' with the ID of 1. The idea is this table data is filled with either 1's or 0's.

If a row with the ID of 1 has the number 1 for the column "campaign_1", then the user with the ID of 1 is approved for the campaign with the ID of 1 in the campaign table. If it were 0 then they're not approved for it. The same logic applies for columns "campaign_2", "campaign_3" etc..

Anyways, the issue I'm having is displaying this information on a front-end, as I only want the user to be able to see the campaigns they are approved to run in a drop-down list. When the user is logged in it stores their User ID in a session, I'm not sure if there's a way around it with this method.

Is there any way to get around this? Please note I've done this in procedural PHP as I'm still in my early days, so if anyone has a solution along these lines it would be much appreciated. Sorry if it's a little confusing. I am aware it's a bit ham-fisted, but I just want it to work first.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all be helpful.

Comment: _"for example the column "campaign_1" is relevant to the campaign in 'tbl_campaigns' with the ID of 1"_ Don't do this. You should never have to modify the schema (i.e., add a new column) as part of the day-to-day operation of your app (i.e., when a new campaign row is inserted.) Instead create a [join table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Comment: Cheers Alex, edited so it doesn't have to do this anymore. I did think it was bad practice but wasn't entirely sure on another way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your schema needs to be improved, as the table structure should not have to change every time that you add a new campaign.

1. keep tables tbl_campaigns and tbl_users as they are
2. create table tbl_permissions with 4 fields (id, user_id, campaign_id and permission)

To check if a user has permission use a query like this:

```
SELECT permission FROM tbl_permissions WHERE user_id = ? AND campaign_id = ?
```

So, every time you create a campaign add a corresponding record to the tbl_permissions table. No need to add a new column.

Comment: Thanks for this Manny, that's a much better way to do it. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice to do this is as follows:
- Create HTML to show to the user(if you don't have it, let me know so i can work on one you can use)
- Create JS archive that will be in charge of calling PHP file and show the result in your HTML(if you don't know how to make it let me know so i can help you)
- Create PHP file, this is going to be in charge of consulting your data base and give the result disired for your select (if you don't know how to make it, let me know)

It is pretty easy to make this work, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to this. I have all of that in place, think I got enough to go from though for now. :)